# Stop character at maze wall Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, maze

I am making a maze game, and I'm using a table for the maze layout. The character moves flawlessly, but it goes through the walls For the walls, I am using something like  `<td style="border-right:10px solid #000000;">`. It works, but the character is pretty much a ghost. Is there a way to make the character stop when it reaches a `border`? My maze is at http://thomaswd.com/maze.

Comment: Please post the relevant piece of code here.

Comment: replicate the problem in a jsfiddle

Comment: After you've fixed the problem, the question doesn't make any sense anymore. If you paste the related code here the question will be useful in the future as well. That said, this sounds like a too localized question in any case.

Comment: It's like asking "how does Mario find the princess", there really is'nt a short answer related to a piece of code?

Comment: I mean, try to locate the part of the code which is involved in the problem, and add it to your question.

Comment: There's no way to detect actual `border` of any element, since it's only a property of the elements. Instead you've to check, if your "character" is just moving to an other element. Also Timothée Groleau gave you a good advice for this in this your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14890078/1169519) question.

Comment: sorry, let me make my question more clear.

I need to make my character stop when it reaches a border. I am using a variable for my character, and the table cells all have `id`s. The `id`s correspond to my character's variable. My character isn't actually an image, it's just the background of the table cell. So I need it to not execute the `down()` or `left()` function if it's current square has a border on one of its sides. Hope that makes it more clear. Again-my maze is at http://thomaswd.com/maze. Thanks!

Comment: As i said in my previous comment, there's no way to detect a collision to the element's border. Instead you need to check, if your "rat" is just going to move to an other element. Unfortenately attempted to vote close this question as an exact duplicate : (. If you won't get (good) answers to your question, rather improve your question, than ask a new-one about exactly same subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, and the walls are shown by the class on the cell, you could check if the cell you're trying to move into has a wall using jQuery's `hasClass` method.

```
function up() {
    //check if the cell has a border on the bottom
    if ($("#td" + (algernon - 8)).hasClass('b')) return;
    $("td").css("background","transparent");
    algernon -= 8;
    setTimeout("refresh()", 0);
}

function down() {
    //check if the cell has a border on the top
    if ($("#td" + (algernon + 8)).hasClass('t')) return;
    $("td").css("background","transparent");
    algernon += 8;
    setTimeout("refresh()", 0);
}

function leftclick() {
    //check if the cell has a border on the right
    if ($("#td" + (algernon - 1)).hasClass('r')) return;
    $("td").css("background","transparent");
    algernon -= 1;
    setTimeout("refresh()", 0);
}

function rightclick() {
    //check if the cell has a border on the left
    if ($("#td" + (algernon + 1)).hasClass('l')) return;
    $("td").css("background","transparent");
    algernon += 1;
    setTimeout("refresh()", 0);
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you!!! I've been trying to accomplish this for days!

Comment: I tried it, and it works for `up()` and `left click()` but not for the other ones

Comment: Interesting... Did I get the classes right? I'm at work right now so I can't test it myself, but if you can wait two hours I'll be right on it..

Answer (score 1):

Save the cell in which the rat is in, then when a move is requested, check if the current cell has a border on the direction the user is trying to go or the future cell has a border in the opposite direction, and just abort the move request if it does.  If the user clicks right, for example, check if the current cell has a right border or the cell into which the rat would move has a left border.